# Some issue with image in nextjs

Tags: html, css, next.js

I am using Image package of nextjs but I am having some blank space on bottom of the image

js code

```html
<div className={css.footer_middle_content_right}>
    <h2>Follow me on Instagram</h2>
    <div className={`${css.footer_instagram_gallery_grid}`}>
         <div className={css.insta_img}>
             <Image src={testimg} alt="a" width={120} height={120} />
             <div className={css.img_filter} />
         </div>
         <div className={css.insta_img}>
             <Image src={testimg} alt="a" width={120} height={120} />
             <div className={css.img_filter} />
         </div>
         <div className={css.insta_img}>
               <Image src={testimg} alt="a" width={120} height={120} />
               <div className={css.img_filter} />
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.footer_instagram_gallery_grid {
 display: -ms-grid;
 display: grid;
 grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
 -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 -ms-grid-rows: auto;
 grid-template-rows: auto;
 grid-row-gap: 16px;
 grid-column-gap: 16px;
 width: fit-content;
}
.insta_img {
 position: relative;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
 -ms-flex-pack: center;
 justify-content: center;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 24px;
 width: 120px;
}
.img_filter {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0%;
 top: 0%;
 right: 0%;
 bottom: 0%;
 /* display: none; */
 background-color: #000;
 opacity: 0.66;
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsele.png)

[nextjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAj7G.png)

Nextjs is wrapping image with some weird span and that span has position: relative property, if i remove it, it works fine but i don't know where to remove it from the code or any solution

[after removing property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW6ms.png)

Comment: Adding images inline instead of linking to them allows for easier reference and removed the possibility of link expiration in the future.